# Iptables with Apache server

Tags: apache2, iptables

I'm tying to use iptables to allow new connections to the server and allow returned traffic and Drop any thing else.
I've used the following rules with a lot of changes and it works perhaps I can't register this process in log file (kern.log) the rules are:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.200 -d 192.168.1.100 -p tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "HTTP REQ recevied"
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.200 -d 192.168.1.100 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.100 -d 192.168.1.200 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "HTTP RES sent"
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.100 -d 192.168.1.200 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

When I tried different examples register in log works but with this example never work.

Why I can't register this in log file?

Comment: What are the other examples you tried that worked?

Comment: like using LOG for dropped packets (iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Dropped Packets")

Comment: Cant tell from what you posted. Can you explain how you tested this and post example logs ?